# JS function works just sometimes

Tags: javascript, html

As the title says, I have a JavaScript function that doesn't always work and I don't know why.
JS:

```
function weapon() {
    var players = document.getElementById("playersList").value.split(",")

    var rand2
    var newPlayers = ""
    var num = players.length - 1

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * num)
        newPlayers += (players[rand2].trim() + ",")
        if (i != num) {
            newPlayers += "\n"
        }
        players.splice(rand2, 1)
    }

    newPlayers += players[0]
    document.getElementById("playersList").value = newPlayers
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="playersList"></textarea>
<button onclick="weapon()">RANDOMIZE</button>
```

There's actually more code in the function but that portion works every time.

Comment: what errors do you get how doesn't it work?

Comment: how do you load the js code ? is it part of html file or loaded from remote js file ?

Comment: If you only have one player, and you use `var num = players.length - 1` what value do you think `num` is going to be in the loop, and how will that change the output?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code can intermittently fail at this line:

```
  newPlayers += (players[rand2].trim() + ",")
```

At the end of your `for` loop, you call:

```
  players.splice(rand2, 1)
```

where `splice` [mutates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the state of `players`, and reduces the amount of items in the array by 1.

When the next iteration of the loop is called, `rand2` has the possibility of generating a value that is greater than the amount of items in the `players` array. You will then receive an error if you try to access an index position which doesn't exist.